# SQL filtering data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, cursor, filtering

I have table with sales documents and invoices eg

```
SalesDoc | Invoice | InvoiceType
------------------------------------
Doc1     | Inv1    | A
Doc1     | Inv2    | B
Doc1     | Inv3    | C
Doc2     | Inv1    | A
Doc2     | Inv2    | C
Doc3     | Inv1    | A
Doc3     | Inv2    | B
```

Each Sales document can have more than one invoice eg standard invoice or proforma..

I need to filter that table to receive below table

So If for Sales doc exist incoice C then show only this row for that sales doc, 
if not then check for type B and then for type A.

```
SalesDoc | Invoice | InvoiceType
-----------------------------------
Doc1     | Inv3    | C
Doc2     | Inv2    | C
Doc3     | Inv2    | B
```

I know that I can store sales docs in temp table and then loop (using cursor) and filter source table to delete unnecessary records
But I want to be sure if is  any other solution than loop to achieve it

Thanks 
Tomek

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the greater logic, you could do this with aggregates:

```
Select  SalesDoc, Max(Invoice) as Invoice, Max(InvoiceType) as InvoiceType
FROM MYSALESTABLE
GROUP BY SalesDoc
```

Comment: Thanks, With little modification works great. My real invoice types are  (from most important ) 5 , M , U . So my final query looks like <pre> SELECT DeliveryNo, max(InvoiceNo), MAX(DocTypeVal) FROM (
Select *,
 CASE 
  WHEN DocType = 'M' THEN 3
  WHEN DocType = '5' THEN 2
  WHEN DocType = 'U' THEN 1
 END as DocTypeVal
FROM ##temp
) as t GROUP BY DeliveryNo </pre>